# How to change ios keyboard language

Tags: ios, keyboard

How to change ios keyboard language, for example, i have 3 textfields, when textfield1 `becomeFirstResponder`, i want to use emoji keyboard, when textfield2 `becomeFirstResponder`, i want to use english keyboard, when textfield3 `becomeFirstResponder`, i want to use chinese keyboard, is there any way to do it? I had not found some API in Apple Document, could you give me an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a user defined setting and can not change it by the Programming.